# Risks of Updating CentOS' coreutils-5.97

Tags: centos, command-line, upgrade

It turned out that our production machine, running under CentOS, didn't have any timeout command, and we need to upgrade its core utilities (current version is coreutils-5.97).

Is it safe to upgrade this package?

Applications deployed on this machine are ran by Apache Tomcat Web server.

Comment: timelimit or timeout, compile it by hand if the server is so critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

coreutils try really hard to be backwards compatible, though there isn't much point updating all utilities as that would add extra risk for no gain. You should be able to add just timeout using something like:

```
tar -xf coreutils-8.25.tar.xz && cd coreutils-8.25 &&
./configure --quiet && make && make check &&
cp src/timeout /usr/local/bin
```